# Speaking Loshon Hara about another Jew to a Gentile

Tags: halacha, gentiles, loshon-hara, contemporary-halacha

Can I say Loshon Hara about another Jew to a Gentile? For example: If Reuven tells Roy that Yehudah is a stupid person. Is Reuven doing an Aveira?

Comment: _Lashon Hara_ to a gentile may actually go over the line to be considered _mesira_, depending on the context.  As such, it is quite a bit more severe.

Comment: @Menachem depending on what type of lashon hara we're talking about. If it's not something that's against the law fir which that person can be called​ to court--it's not a crime--then probably it's not called a Mesira but just disparagement

Comment: If you found my answer satisfactory please consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if just saying someone is stupid is Lashon Hara, it depends on the context and how it's said.

But in general, when slandering to a Gentile, besides the sin of speaking slander about your fellow man, you are also desecrating the name of God by bad-mouthing his children.

---

Source: https://torah.org/learning/halashon-chapter8/

> "One who violates this and slanders a Jew before gentiles flagrantly
>   rebels against Torat Moshe Rabbeinu (the Torah which Moses taught us),
>   as is discussed in the Shulchan Aruch, Choshen Mishpat 26."

Comment: While sources would definitely improve the quality of this answer, I can't agree more with its content!

Comment: @JoshK added source